# How to revert back the installed package

Tags: aem, crx

Is it possible to revert back the installed package(if any content modified with package installation) in CQ5 from the package manager console.?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. According to the [documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/package_manager.html):

> You can perform the following actions with packages:
>
> - **Uninstall packages**, which reverts to the snapshop of in-repository content at the time of the last installation.

1. Just go to the CRX Package manager and click on a package.
2. You'll be given a blue edit bar below the package details.
3. Click on "More" on the right-hand side, and then "Uninstall".
4. Check the logs to make sure it completes successfully.

[image: Context menu for the Package Manager]

Comment: Thank you anotherdave, If i install the package A,B, & C sequentially in the same order. and after for few reasons if i uninstall package A. will the changes done by package B and C still be there or do i need to reinstall the package B and C?

Comment: Ah, that's interesting question :) I *presume*, that it will look at the timestamp of the A install & rollback to this point, & so you would lose B&C, though I haven't tried it. If reinstalling B&C is complex, you could possibly create a package on another environment running a pre-A version, containing just the files A has affected & revert that way — by performing another install over the top rather than rolling back.